# Driving an sc_out from an sc_signal

Tags: c++, systemc

Consider the following example, where one module's output (`inner::out`) is supposed to drive two outputs (`outer::out` and `outer::out2`) of the upper hierarchy level:

```
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(inner) {
    sc_out<bool> out;

    SC_CTOR(inner) : out("out") {
        SC_THREAD(doit);
    };

    void doit() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            out != out;
            wait(10, SC_NS);
        }
    }
};


SC_MODULE(outer) {
    sc_out<bool> out, out2;

    SC_CTOR(outer) : out("out"), out2("out2"), i("inner"), out_s("out_s") {
        i.out(out_s);

        out(out_s);
        out2(out_s);
    }

    inner i;

    sc_signal<bool> out_s;
};


int sc_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    outer o("outer");

    sc_start(1, SC_MS);

    return 0;
}
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5s2C#

Running this results in the following error:

```
Error: (E115) sc_signal<T> cannot have more than one driver: 
 signal `outer.out_s' (sc_signal)
 first driver `outer.inner.out'  (sc_out)
 second driver `outer.out2' (sc_out)
In file: ../../../../src/sysc/communication/sc_signal.cpp:73
```

It seems that `outer::out2` is considered to *drive* `out_s` instead of *being driven* by it. Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking? Is there a way to make this work without using an explicit `SC_METHOD` sensitive to `inner::out` inside `outer`?

Answer (score 1):

Your design describes a signal driven by three different output ports -- not what you want.

You may want to use **port-to-port binding**. If you're not familiar with the concept, section 4.1.3 "Port binding and export binding" in the SystemC LRM describes it like this:

> When port A is bound to port B, and port B is bound to channel C, the effect shall be the same as if port A were bound directly to channel C. Wherever this standard refers to port A being bound to channel C, it shall be assumed this means that port A is bound either directly to channel C or to another port that is itself bound to channel C according to this very same rule. This same rule shall apply when binding exports.

With port-to-port binding, you can bind `inner::out` directly to both `outer::out` and `outer::out2`, without a signal in between. For example:

```cpp
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(inner) {
    sc_port<sc_signal_inout_if<bool>, 2> out;

    SC_CTOR(inner) : out("out") {
        SC_THREAD(doit);
    };

    void doit() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            out[0]->write(!out[0]->read());
            out[1]->write(!out[1]->read());
            wait(10, SC_NS);
        }
    }
};


SC_MODULE(outer) {
    sc_out<bool> out, out2;

    SC_CTOR(outer) : out("out"), out2("out2"), i("inner") {
        i.out(out);
        i.out(out2);
    }

    inner i;
};


int sc_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    outer o("outer");
    sc_signal<bool> out_s;
    sc_signal<bool> out2_s;

    o.out(out_s);
    o.out2(out2_s);

    sc_trace_file *tf = sc_create_vcd_trace_file("trace");
    sc_trace(tf, out_s, "out_s");
    sc_trace(tf, out2_s, "out2_s");

    sc_start(1, SC_MS);

    sc_core::sc_close_vcd_trace_file(tf);

    return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of things to note in the above code:

- `inner::out` is declared as a `sc_port<sc_signal_inout_if<bool>, 2>`, which is basically the same as an `sc_out` but allows the port to be bound to two channels. `sc_out` can only be bound to a single channel.
- When writing to `inner::out`, you have to specify the bound channel you are driving. This is done with the `[]` operator -- see `inner::doit()` above where both bound channels are driven.

When run, the above code produces a trace.vcd file that shows the levels on the two signals, `out_s` and `out2_s`, toggling.

Having explained all that, I'm not sure that it's really what you want. Having an output port fan out like that is pretty unusual. Do you really need two output ports on `outer`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite what I wanted since I'd need to change `inner` to reflect requirements imposed on `outer`. I was hoping that there was a way to connect a single `sc_signal` to `inner::out` and drive two outputs of `outer` (the same way as you can, for example, in VHDL). Still, it seems that this is simply a shortcoming of SystemC.

Regarding your question whether I really need that: unfortunately I do for pin compatibility with a VHDL model.

Answer (score 1):

Error: (E115) sc_signal cannot have more than one driver:

Can be solved by using SC_MANY_WRITERS.

for example:

```
sc_signal < bool, SC_MANY_WRITERS > reset_sig;
```

and then for a module called initializer we can bind this signal as such:

```
initializer<int, 16> init("init");

init.reset(reset_sig);
```

now for the other module, producer module, which is using the same signal:

```
producer<int, 16> prc("prc");

prc.resetIn(reset_sig);
prc.resetOut(reset_sig);
```